# Save Constant GET Variable In A Session

Tags: php, mysql

Can some explain to me the best way to store a `$_GET` variable in a session and the only way the `sessions` changes is when we verify the data the session is being change to is different from the `GET` variable.

Currently i have

```
 $tid = clean_get($_GET['tid']);
```

in a global file which is included on every page the problem with that is the value of `$tid` will be erased and not stored in a `session` like i want it to once the user is not on a page with `$tid` set in the url.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you get $_GET['tid'] in url then set session again by that new value otherwise restore it from session. Thats it.

```
session_start();
$tid = (isset($_GET['tid']) && $_GET['tid']!="") ? clean_get($_GET['tid']) : $_SESSION['tid'];
```

Try this and tell me is it solved?

Comment: i need a way to set the variable rather than the session no errors it just doesn't fix my problem

Comment: you are geat thanks it works great, ive been working on trying to find a fix for almost 2 days thanks so much

Comment: You can just mark my answer as right below the up down arror. YOU will get right mark and mark it as solved thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use a function like [isset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) to see if it is being sent. Only then should you replace it:

```
if(isset($_GET['tid']))
{
    $tid = clean_get($_GET['tid'])
    // Do stuff to change session data.
}
```

Comment: im currently doing that                                      [

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is something like

```
session_start();
foreach ($_GET as $key=>$value) {
    $_SESSION['getValues'][$key] = clean_get($value);
}
```

This will store all the values in $_GET in the $_SESSION.  To retrieve the values later, you just have to use `$_SESSION['getValues']['tid']` after calling `session_start()`.

Here I'm assuming that `clean_get()` is just something that formats and/or escapes data that came in from forms, so calling it on each value before sticking into the session will do all that cleaning when needed.

Note: only call `session_start()` once, and make sure you do so before doing anything with `$_SESSION`, otherwise you'll get error messages.

Comment: how would i implement my clean_get function in that?

Comment: @astonishin, I'm not positive what exactly `clean_get()`'s purpose is, but based on my best guess, I've updated the above answer to include it.